# palindrome with a stack using linked lists does not return the correct answer

Tags: java

I have been implementing a Stack by using a linked list. The implementation is the following:

```
public class Node {
    public Object e;
    Node next;
    public Node(Object e){
        this.e=e;
    }
}

public class Stack {
    Nodo last, first;
    int count;
    public void push(Object n){
        Nodo temp=new Nodo(n);
        temp.next=last;
        last=temp;
        if (first==null){
            first=temp;
        }
        count++;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if (count==0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public Object pop(){
        Object obj=null;
        if (isEmpty()){
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            obj=last.e;
            last=last.next;
        }
        count--;
        return obj;
    }
    public void print(){
        Nodo current=last;
        while (current!=null){
            System.out.println(current.e);
            current=current.next;
        }
    }
public boolean palindrome(){
        Stack cadT1=new Stack();
        Stack cadT2=new Stack();
        cadT1=this;
        //System.out.println(this.isEmpty());
        while (this.isEmpty()!=true){
            cadT2.push(this.pop());
        }
        cadT1.print();
        while (cadT1.isEmpty()!=true){
            /*if (!(cadT1.pop().equals(cadT2.pop()))){
                return false;
            }*/
            System.out.println(cadT1.pop()+" "+cadT2.pop());
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I have a problem with the implementation of the palindrome function, in which I am also using stacks. The problem that I have is that it always returns the value of true. I have commented the portion of the code that currently is not working. While analyzing my code I found that when I do the following assignment:

```
cadT1=this;
```

The cadT1 variable is still empty. I have tested this by putting the following line in the while of the palindrome function:

```
System.out.println(cadT1.pop()+" "+cadT2.pop());
```

and I have seen that my code does not execute that line, that is because the condition in the while loop:

```
while (cadT1.isEmpty()!=true){
```

is always set to false.
The running code in my main class is the following:

```
 Stack word=new Stack();
    word.push('a');
    word.push('s');
    word.push('d');
    word.push('f');
    System.out.println(word.palindrome());
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: consider implementing the `peek()` method and use that in logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have already popped all the elements from the current stack with this

```
cadT2.push(this.pop());
```

Now, when you call `cadT1.print()`, it won't print anything (`cadT1` is the reference to the current stack). Hence, `cadT1.isEmpty()` will be true.

What you can do is to iterate the linked list and build the second stack rather than popping the elements from the current stack to build the second stack (If you pop, you won't have any elements in the current stack to compare against).